# PS3 Browser Capabilities

Tags: cross-browser, playstation3

I am trying to find out what the PS3 web browser is like in terms of CSS, JS, Flash, etc.

I found some articles saying it is pretty bad, but these are several years old and the PS3 software is frequently updated so I can't trust things like [this](http://www.design215.com/read.php?title=playstation%203%20browser%20specs).

Can anyone point me at official specs or a recent analysis? Your own test results are welcome but please state how recent they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest specs I could find showed the PS3 getting an ACID3 score of 27 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3) and a similar Wikipedia page details the capabilities of the NetFront engine, which is used by the PS3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFront. These results are from a January 2011 release, but the release notes for subsequent updates don't show any modifications to it.

There are also a few questions on here which can give you a pointer to potential issues such as: [Javascript not working on PS3 Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990445/javascript-not-working-on-ps3-browser).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but thought I'd add to it.

A quick visit to [acid3.acidtests.com](http://acid3.acidtests.com/) shows that my (up-to-date) PS3 is now getting a 99% score. It's actually a little lower since the test *also* requires pixel-perfect rendering and smooth animation, neither of which it has yet. (One of the boxes is gray when it should be yellow, and the animation is jerky.)

[Whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com) shows that it's running **WebKit 531.22.8**, which must be behind the improvement. It's strange that they're using 531 in a 2012 system update since that build is almost three years out of date. But regardless it's a huge leap forward compared to what they had before.

Answer (score 0):

As of PS3 firmware 4.50, a custom fork of the WebKit browser is used that masquerades as Netfront NX. It is roughly equivalent in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript functionality to an iPad 1 running iOS 5.0 in terms of functionality -- except that the PS3 also includes a Flash 9.x runtime. Having the Flash 9 runtime allows for using polyfills for WebSockets, Promises, and other HTML5/ES6 features. It does effectively pass the Acid3 test, which some minor alignment issues like most 2012-era browsers.

A decent JavaScript development setup that is using webpack and Flash 9 polyfills should be able to produce a JS bundle targeting PS3, Xbox 360, and Android 2.x with pretty advanced functionality comparable to modern mobile browsers.